# To view version history along with documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning, version-history

I am working in SharePoint office365 environment. I have enabled versioning for one of my document library. I need to see the document in each version.

Is it possible? If so how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Open the version history and view it.

1. Click on following marked location 
   [image]
2. Click on Version History

   [image]
3. Now click on the document and view the version

[image]

Comment: But this will show only document for the lastest version.I need to track document in each version

Comment: No.. It should show all versions based on your version settings! How many version are you keeping?